# @PostMapping with multiple RequestBody

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, post

I'm very new to Java Spring and have a little Problem.

I wan't to send the employee_id (from employees entity) to assignment entity in the body part (in Postman). Currently it's working, because I'm sending the employee_id as a PathVariable and I'm sending the assignment data with ResponseBody.

```
@PostMapping("/add/{employee_id}")
   public void addEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employee_id", required = false) Long employee_id, 
             @RequestBody Assignment a) {

       Employee employeeById = employeeRepository.findById(employee_id)
               .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Employee not found"));

       a.setEmployee(employeeById);
       assignmentRepository.addAssignment(a);
   }
```

It is working with the url **localhost:8080/add/35**. 35 is the employee_id and the assignment data can be send in the Body (of Postman). What I want to do is, to send the employee_id in the body too (so the url should only be /add), but I could not get it to work.

Like that:

```
{
  "employee_id": 35,
  "title": "abc"
}
```

Edited:

Assignment.java

```
public class Assignment {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   @OneToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
   private Employee employee;

   @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
   private String assignment_title;

   public Assignment() {
   }

   public Assignment(String assignment_title) {
       super();
       this.assignment_title = assignment_title;
   }

   public Integer getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getAssignment_title() {
       return assignment_title;
   }

   public void setAssignment_title(String assignment_title) {
       this.assignment_title = assignment_title;
   }

   public Employee getEmployee() {
       return employee;
   }

   public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
       this.employee = employee;
   }
}
```

AssignmentService.java

```
   public void addAssignment(Assignment e) {
       AssignmentRepository.save(e);
   }
```

AssignmentRepository.java

```
public interface AssignmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Assignment, Integer>{
   
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;
   
   @OneToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
   private User user;

   @Size(min=3, max = 100)
   private String title;

   @Size(min=3, max = 50)
   private String staff;

   private Long degree;

   public Employee() {}

   public Employee( String title, String staff, Long degree) {
       super();
       this.title = title;
       this.staff = staff;
       this.degree = degree;
   }
   
   public Integer getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
       return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
       this.title = title;
   }

   public String getStaff() {
       return staff;
   }

   public void setStaff(String staff) {
       this.staff = staff;
   }

   public Long getDegree() {
       return degree;
   }

   public void setDegree(Long degree) {
       this.degree = degree;
   }

   public User getUser() {
       return user;
   }

   public void setUser(User user) {
       this.user = user;
   }

}
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer>{
   Optional<Employee> findById(Long id);
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure your body type `Assignment` has such property like

```java
public class Assignment {
    public Long employee_id;
    // ommitted
}
```

And get it in your method like

```java
@PostMapping("/add")
public void addEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employee_id", required = false) Long employee_id, @RequestBody Assignment a) {
    Long employee_id = a.employee_id;
    Employee employeeById = employeeRepository.findById(employee_id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Employee not found"));
    a.setEmployee(employeeById);
    assignmentRepository.addAssignment(a);
}
```

But such implementation does not respect HTTP standards.
Please consider that your actual implementation almost respect those standards and you should rename your API this way : `POST URL/v1/employees/{employee_id}`
This [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) explains those standards

*EDIT with provided specifications:*

```java
@PostMapping(values = {"/v1/employees", "/v1/employees/{employee_id}"})
public void addEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employee_id", required = false) Long employee_id, @RequestBody Assignment a) {
    Long yourId = employee_id != null ? employee_id : a.employee_id;
    if (yourId == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No id given"); // Not clean either but implemented by OP
    } else {
        Employee employeeById = employeeRepository.findById(yourId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Employee not found"));
        a.setEmployee(employeeById);
        assignmentRepository.addAssignment(a);
    }
}
```

As the pathvariable is optionnal you try to get it first from url and then from your body object.

*EDIT 2 : An `Assignment` might be created with no Employee_id*
**First case** : You accept that an Assignment might have no Employee.
Simply change your relation from Assignment to Employee :

```java
    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = true)
    private Employee employee;
```

**Second case** : You want to create a new Employee first and then bind it to your assignement as an `Assignment` should always have an `Employee`

```java
@PostMapping(values = {"/v1/employees", "/v1/employees/{employee_id}"})
public void addEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employee_id", required = false) Long employee_id, @RequestBody Assignment a) {
    Long yourId = employee_id != null ? employee_id : a.employee_id;
    Employee employeeById = yourId != null ?
        employeeRepository.findById(yourId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Employee not found"))
        : new Employee("title","staff",2L);
    a.setEmployee(employeeById);
    assignmentRepository.addAssignment(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this way I cannot set employee_id to null. In some scenarios the admin can choose to not add an employee to the assignment. How can I fix that?

Comment: ping @Rosina you must provide multiple Mappings in your `@PostMapping`

Comment: So I didn't change anything It's still like in my question, I just added the edited version from your code (Pathvariable and Long yourid). But I'm still getting following error: The given id must not be null!

Comment: You should then call your repository with `yourId`. And check that it's not null beforehead.

Comment: In that way it's just throwing an error. I want to add the assignment even if the employee_id is not given, if its null. I just tried to put the assignmentRepository.addAssignment(a); in the if function. It's not working either. But I can add the assignment with an employee_id, there is no problem

Comment: Then provide your repository and model

Comment: You should provide Employee class too

Comment: Just added it too

Comment: Also please consider move your algorithm to a Service as @Controller is only supposed to handle user-data and send them to a Service.

Comment: Thank you so much!!